# Two way lookup with Data Lists in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I've got a table with multiple rows and columns.

I created two cells that are data lists - so they are essentially drop down selectors for the rows and columns.

I want to be able to choose from the drop down list selection, and then get what the row and column intersecting value is.

I've tried using vlookup, and index and match, but none of it works. I'm not sure if it is because I am using data lists as the criteria...

I've tried this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Table1[Company], MATCH(B3, Table1[#Headers], 0), FALSE)
```

Where B2 is the data list for the rows, and B3 is the data list for the column, but that didn't work

I've also tried this:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Company], MATCH(Sheet1!B2, Table1[Company], 0), MATCH(Sheet1!B3, Table1[#Headers], 0))
```

But that didn't work either...

Comment: can u try hlookup instead of vlookup

Comment: Can't get that to work either

Comment: Check https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/59482 Do not forget to enter the formula as array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Your INDEX formula looks promising. There is just an error in the first argument. You want `Table1`, not `Table1[Company]`. Like this:

```
=INDEX(Table1, MATCH(Sheet1!B2, Table1[Company], 0), MATCH(Sheet1!B3, Table1[#Headers], 0))
```